# How can I use shadowColor on Android device?

Tags: react-native

As I know shadowOffset, Opacity, Radius is used for IOS, not Android, but i still added.
For Android, shadowColor should be enough i guess, if not, then I added elevation for it to work.

I try to give some shadow to some fields. I defined by `style={styles.tracking}`where i want to give some shadow.

I added these codes there:  but it doesnt work, neither it gives an error.

```
shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 3,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.27,
    shadowRadius: 4.65,

    elevation: 6,
```

here is styles.tracking

```
tracking:{
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 3,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.27,
    shadowRadius: 4.65,

    elevation: 6,
    flexDirection:"row",
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent:"space-between", 
    marginVertical:20,
  
  },
```

How can I show the shadow in this code?

```
<View style={styles.tracking}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
              <Deliver style={styles.leftIcon} height={30} width={30} fill={"#008000"} />
              <View style={styles.adressMargin}>
                <Text style={styles.trackingId}>CKR90825567</Text>
                <Text style={styles.trackingAdress}>Jakarta - Surabaya</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.rightIcon}>
              <Circle style={styles.rightMargin} height={8} width={8} fill={"#008000"} />
              <Text style={styles.delivered}>Delivered</Text>
            </View>
          </View>


tracking:{
    flexDirection:"row",
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent:"space-between",   
    marginVertical:20,
    },

  delivered: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 17,
    color: "green",
    marginRight: 20,
  },
  leftIcon:{
    marginLeft:30,
  },
  rightIcon: {
    flexDirection:"row",
    alignItems:"center",
  },

 adressMargin: {
    marginLeft:30,
  },
  trackingId: {
    fontSize:20,
    fontWeight:"bold",
  },
  trackingAdress:{
    color:"grey",
  },
```

the screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

Shadow does not work in Android. You can use a View as background to apply shadow. Example

```
<View
        style={{
          padding: 10,
          width: 200,
          height: 100,
          backgroundColor: 'grey',
          borderRadius: 7,
          zIndex: 2,
          elevation: 40,
        }}>
        <Text
          style={{
            textAlign: 'center',
            color: 'white',
          }}>
          Button
        </Text>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3',
          marginLeft: 25,
          marginTop: -100,
          borderRadius: 7,
          width: 195,
          height: 108,
        }}></View>
```

End Result

[image]

Comment: thank you, I understand your explanation. But why did you use `marginTop:-100` for the second view which is used for shadow?

Comment: To have my second view behind the first(dark) one. You can remove marginTop and see the result.

Comment: Could you please look at my edit in the question? As I copy your code, okay it works perfectly. But  i couldnt do this on my code. I want to give a shadow to my View which i styled as `styles.tracking`  Should i only add elevation in my View, and then make a second View under it, as you did in the second View?

Comment: Okay I'll look.

Comment: @user15775693 You have to add elevation to View for which you need the shadow. Then for the second View apply height and marginTop slightly less than the height of the first one. Can you share Snack for your project if you're finding any difficult to implement this?

Comment: Thank you, ill try to do what you said soon, and share it with you

Comment: I just uploaded codes, since i have many icons, i couldnt add them on expo snack, cause i deleted them, would be hard time to download them again. And i just screenshoot of the screen i have on android. But i dont understand why i happen to have that screen, the middle one seems strange, i must have something wrong. https://snack.expo.io/4fDA-1T8x  I added screenshot of android, in my edit of the question, thanks